# Get an Xml page to my Android App

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to layout this simpe XML http://3pi.tf/test.xml to parse it later but first of all i just want to layout it to my Android App..

So there is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    TextView textview1;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Log.v(TAG, "test1");
  textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
  Log.v(TAG, "test2");
  getXmlTask task = new getXmlTask(textview1 , "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml");
  Log.v(TAG, "test3");
  task.execute(); 
 }
}
```

And there is my getXmltask.java

```
public class getXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    private static final String TAG2 = null;

    private WeakReference<TextView> textViewReference;
    private String url;

    public getXmlTask(TextView textview1, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void GetXmlTask(TextView textview, String url) {
        this.textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textview);
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.v(TAG2, "testnew");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.v(TAG2, "testurl");
        HttpResponse rp = null;
        try {
            rp = hc.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v(TAG2, "testpost");

        if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            try {
                return EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Error";
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
        TextView textView = textViewReference.get();
        if(textView != null) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }       
    }

}
```

with some logcat i could find the line where the "cursor can't pass"... 
so the logcat "testnew" is OK but not the logcat "testurl" so it means that this line

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
```

is not okay right ?? can someone help me please ? 
I just want to layout this xml to my android App if someone could tell me how it will be great ! ^^

for some more informations, the app starts with a white page and after few seconds i get this pop-up message saying that my app has been stopped...

Comment: you need to get xml so use `HTTP GET` method

Comment: I replace Post to Get but I got the same logcat.. Testurl can't pass :/ ^^

Comment: did you try the code in my post??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below in `doInbackground`

```
 String _respons;
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... sUrl) {
 try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://3pi.tf/test.xml");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    _respons=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Log.i(".........",""+_respons);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
     return _respons;

 }
```

Comment: now the app doesn't crash but he not layout the xml http://3pi.tf/test.xml .. :/ by the way thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Nemka i do not understand your comment. No layout is there. Its a xml file that is what you get in `String _respons=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);` your understanding of layout and xml is very wrong. Log that response and check.

Comment: Actually I just want my app to show the XML http://3pi.tf/test.xml ^^ is it possible ? to parse it later because I want later to extract some informations about this xml with XMLParser

Comment: @Nemka first check if you get the response `Log.i(".........",""+_respons);`. Check the logcat. yes it is possible. the resposne that you get you need to pass it to `onpostExecute` by returning it in `doInbackground`. i see only this `return "Error";` you do not  `return _respons`

Comment: i put a Log.v(TAG2,"testgeturl") after HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); and it didn't show :/

Comment: @Nemka you din't log it right. `Log.v(TAG2,"testgeturl")` logs `testgeturl`. pls check the docs of `Log` and check my edited answer now. it will work 100%

Comment: Man you just wonderful !! But now i have all my informations in logcat so can i Parse it after to get values i want ?

Comment: @Nemka absolutely. you can parse the xml without a problem if you do it right and pls mark the answer as accepted. You need to parse the response string which is the xml